# How to get a boolean value from Neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j

I'm running a query, where I want to get a simple bool value. 
The problem is converting the result to a bool. I know that result[0] contain a key, which is the last part of the query, and an array of values, where the bool is. Now all I need is getting that bool out of Values.

```
public async Task<List<IRecord>> GetRecordsAsync(string query)
{
    IDriver _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "project"));
    IAsyncSession _session = _driver.AsyncSession(o => o.WithDatabase("neo4j"));
    List<IRecord> records = new List<IRecord>();
    try
    {

        IResultCursor cursor = await _session.RunAsync(query);

        while (await cursor.FetchAsync())
        {
            records.Add(cursor.Current);
        }

        await cursor.ConsumeAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        await _session.CloseAsync();
    }
    return records;
}
public void GetBool()
{

    string query = "MATCH(p: User { userName: 'something'}), (b: User { userName: 'somethingElse'}) RETURN EXISTS((p)-[:Follows]->(b) )";
    var result = GetRecordsAsync(query).Result;

    var only = result[0];
    bool finalResult=...
}
```

Comment: How does result[0] looks like? Whats in it?

Comment: The first in a list of IRecord

Comment: It has Keys and Values. Keys has what looks like an array of strings, but with one value: "EXISTS((p)-[:Follows]->(b) )". Values has what seems to me a dictionary. The key in Values[0] is the same key, as the one mentioned earlier. And value is true(bool)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've figured it out. I only had to insert one line:

bool value = only.Values["EXISTS((p)-[:Follows]->(b) )"].As();